# Accessing distinguished fileds in assign shape (Biztalk)

Tags: biztalk

I am constructing a multipart message in construct shape. That message has a body part with distinguished field, which i want to assign in assignment shape:

[image]

As you can see, intellisense is suggesting me to select a node with my distinguished field. But when i select it, i get an error!

[image]

I've faced this before, and restarting VS always helped. But not this time :(

Comment: Is there anything else in the Orchestration either named 'message' or with 'message' anywhere in the namespace?  The Orchestration Designer has problem with those situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Message is a reserved word in XLang.  Can you change the name of the element/attribute that backs this distinguished field to something else?  If that does not work, you could always XPath to the element to read it and use it.  Last if those two don't work, you could make this a promoted property where you are able to specify the name yourself.

Here is the list of reserved words.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa547020.aspx

Comment: Yes, Ben Runchey is more right.  It's because 'message' is reserved.  Actually, is should never have worked.